# Getting an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" error but don't know how?

Tags: c#

my code's throwing up an out of range error while I'm looping through a List, but I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
        for(int neighborCounter = neighborList.Count - 1; neighborCounter >= 0; neighborCounter--)
        {
            for(int toBeCheckedCounter = toBeChecked.Count - 1; toBeCheckedCounter >= 0; toBeCheckedCounter--)
            {
                Vector2 tile1 = neighborList[neighborCounter];
                Vector2 tile2 = toBeChecked[toBeCheckedCounter];

                if(tile1 == tile2)
                {
                    neighborList.Remove(neighborList[neighborCounter]);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you guys need any more context let me know. The error appears on the line where tile1 is declared. It looks like I'm trying to access an element that neighborList doesn't contain.

Comment: Does the list contain duplicates? You're removing items by value so you are potentially removing values out of order and have some unintended consequences.  You should be removing items by index instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `neighborCounter` is an outer loop. If you remove enough from the `neighborList`, since `neighborCounter` is not moving while `toBeCheckedCounter` moves, there can be a point where `neighborCounter = neighborList.Count`, which will trigger your `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

I suggest you avoid removing in a loop or a foreach. You can list all of the items you will be removing and do it after,i.e.

```
if(tile1 == tile2)
{
  itemsToRemove.Add(neighborList[neighborCounter]); // itemsToRemove can be a HashSet
}
```

Comment: I think, what he is trying to say is, that it will crash, whenever you remove an element. The element will be removed and during the next Iteration you are trying to check against a non-existant index, cause you just removed that index.

Answer (score 0):

Tyress is right with his explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35546304/4927547

Another way you can avoid getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException would be rewriting your code like this:

```
foreach (Vector2 neighbor in neighborList)
{
    foreach (Vector2 toBeCheckedItem in toBeChecked)
    {
        if (neighbor == toBeCheckedItem)
        {
            neighborList.Remove(neighbor);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way

```
foreach (Vector2 toBeCheckedItem in toBeChecked)
{
    if (neighborList.Contains(toBeCheckedItem))
    {
        neighborList.Remove(toBeCheckedItem);
    }
}
```